# how to validate fields with html5 & sharepoint 2010 webpart?

Tags: web-part, validation, ajax-control-tookit, html5

Recently, I tried to get validated fields with `RegularExpressionValidator`. When I deployed the webpart, the click event is not working as expected.

I hear that `RegularExpressionValidator` is not compatible with SharePoint 2010 (I guess an ajaxtoolkit issue?). Another way to validate fields would be HTML5, but how can I setup and make that approach work?