# Fields validation with Javascript in custom WebPart - SharePoint Online -

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, visual-web-part, validation

I'm currently developing a `SandBox WebPart` for `SharePoint Online` (2013) which have two TextBoxes.

I'm trying to add the following code for validate the Email and Subject TextBoxes once the `Button` click event raises.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm() {

        //Declare variables.
        var txtError = document.getElementById('<%= lblMsg.ClientID %>');
        var subjectCmp = document.getElementById('<%= txtSubject.ClientID %>');
        var emailCmp = document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>');
        var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

        txtError.innerHTML = "";

        //Subject.
        if (subjectCmp.innerHTML.length === 0) {
            txtError.innerHTML = txtError.innerHTML + "Field 'Subject' is required. \n";
        }

        //Email.
        if (emailCmp.innerHTML.length === 0) {
            txtError.innerHTML = txtError.innerHTML + "Field 'Email' is required. \n";
        }
        else {
            if (!emailPattern.test(emailCmp.innerHTML)) {
                txtError.innerHTML = txtError.innerHTML + "'Email' field is invalid. \n";
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Here is the sample Visual WebPart:

```
<div class="csFila">
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" Text="Email" runat="server" CssClass="cslbl" />
    <div class="csctrl">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="255" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="csFila">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" Text="Subject" runat="server" CssClass="cslbl" />
    <div class="csctrl">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" MaxLength="255" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="csFila">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" Text="Subject" runat="server" CssClass="cslbl" />
    <div class="csctrl">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" MaxLength="255" />
    </div>
</div>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="cspnlCarga" runat="server">
     <asp:FileUpload ID="File2" runat="server" />
     <asp:Panel ID="pnl_btn_field" runat="server">
         <input id="addFile" type="button" value="Send" onclick="validateForm();" /><br />
     </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
<span id="TxtError" title="Here shows the error message."/>
```

The issue is, even when the TextBoxes has text on it, the Javascript function shows the "Field X is required" message.

The Visual WebPart doesn't has a `form` tag and I tested this code in a pure HTML page with the same results.

My requieremnt is validate these fields for preceed with the full functionality (register these info in a List).

What I tested:

- Add `validateForm` function in a asp.net Button in the `OnClientClick` property.
- Try validate a single field *(only for discard other code which may disable validation functionality).*
- Create a simple `HTML` page and test these code.

N.B: *There's no much what to do in SharePoint Online AFAIK,* but in resumen, I need to validate these data before call *server code which have the full functionality* which can be resumed in these steps:

1. Create a document in a Document Library.
2. Generate registers in more that one `List`.
3. Query and update generated registers *step two.*

Is in somehow [related with this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91611/how-to-validate-fields-with-html5-sharepoint-2010-webpart), but I'm not using AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: What is `asuntoCmp`? Is this supposed to be `emailCmp`?

Comment: @Submits No. It's `subjectCmp` instead. My bad. My code is in Spanish, fixed and thanks.

Comment: Just an fyi, sandboxed solutions such as this is deprecated in SharePoint Online.  It's advised to switch to the new app model.

Comment: @wjervis Thanks. I'll talk with my coworker for if we can switch to app model _however I do not have such knowledges_. Any tutorial for learn How to develop apps for SharePoint Online are welcome: [My question on Meta.SharePoint ask about this specific topic BTW.](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/are-questions-about-resources-for-learning-sp-development-on-topic)

Comment: @Mauricio, I learned it by just diving into it.  Microsoft has some pretty good [code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Apps-for-SharePoint-sample-64c80184), and there are a lot of examples around.  The main thing is that REST is a more enticing way to perform CRUD operations (only method for uploading files > 1.5MB as well). [This](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-csom-vs.-rest-...-my-preference-and-why) link explains the differences between CSOM and REST (I should note that it's biased towards REST).

Comment: @wjervis Thanks. I really appreciate. For the moment I must complete this task while the coworker decide if we switch to app model _or if he can do it better_, anyway, maybe there's a solution for this requierement. Also, the WebPart must allow files bigger than the 1.5MB _increase the limit is not a option AFAIK_, so I know that this will be hard and the time doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research in the Internet I found finally the solution, [here's the answer and the credits belong to him.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26460071)

I'm not sure why the `WebPart` couldn't *or can't* detect the `ASP.NET` controls in `var` variables *maybe there's some about the `if` conditionals...*

Here's the full validation code that I'm using in the `WebPart` that I develop a few days ago.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {

    //Declare variables.
    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    /*For some unknown reason, fields to validate (if they're declared on variables type "var") are NOT detected.*/

    //Validate fields (ASP.NET fields).
    if (document.getElementById('<%= txtSubject.ClientID %>').value.length == 0) {
        alert("Field ''Subject'' is required.");
        document.getElementById('<%= txtAsunto.ClientID %>').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').value.length == 0) {
        alert("Field ''Email'' is required.");
        document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        if (!emailPattern.test(document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').value)) {
            alert("Field ''Email'' is invalid.");
            document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
            return false;
        }
        else{                   
            //Your code...
        }
    }
}</script>
```

*N.B: The following code was tested and it works in pure `HTML`, `SharePoint 2010` and `SharePoint 2013 (Online)`.*